# Script to update Google Form from Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Here's my problem:

I can't seem to piece this info together nor find it anywhere even though it seems simple enough. When I find help, they just tell me to enter it manually (but my users can't be trusted) or make a new form (not an option).

What I need is to be able to keep:

- the same google form
- it's ID and link to the same spreadsheet
- the same 20 "paragraph text" questions (titles remain the same).

There can't be any new questions or anything that would change the name or layout of the response destination page in the spreadsheet.

However, what I want is:

- ***to update the help text below these questions from twenty cells in the spreadsheet***. If my cells are from a range called questions!b2:b19 in the same spreadsheet, how do I use a script to take their contents and write over and update the help text in these paragraph questions on the google form?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to create your [form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) in AppScript. With your form created, you can then use AppScript to access your [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app). Read the information from the sheet and use it to create the help text on your questions with [setHelpText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#setHelpText(String)).

Here's a basic sample.

```
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<ID>");
var val = ss.getRange(<RANGE>).getValue();

item.setTitle('Question');
item.setHelpText(val);
item.setChoices([
        item.createChoice('ONE'),
        item.createChoice('TWO'),
        item.createChoice('THREE')
    ]);
```