# Creating a google form from a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a google spreadsheet to automatically convert into a google form, so i don't have to manually enter all the questions into the google form.

I am writing google app script and managed to get all the questions.I am trying to divide the form in to sections depending on the first column of the sheet. So if the first column is "1" questions corresponding to it should be on the first section and if it is "2" it should create another section.And so on.

How can i do that? what will be the code? I have attached the google sheet as here [Google spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4d9Y.png)

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = ss.getDataRange(); 
  var data = range.getValues();
  var numberRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numberColumns = range.getNumColumns();
  var firstRow = 1;
  var form = FormApp.openById('1hIQCLT_JGLcvjz44vXTvP5ziia6NnwCqWBxYT4h2uCk');


  var items = form.getItems();
  var ilength = items.length;
  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++)

  {

    form.deleteItem(0);

  }

  for(var i=0;i<numberRows;i++)
  {
    Logger.log(data);
    var questionType = data[i][0]; 
    if (questionType=='')

    {
      continue;
    }
    //choose the type of question from the first column of the spreadsheet
    else if(questionType=='1')
    {
      var rowLength = data[i].length;
      var currentRow = firstRow+i;
      var currentRangeValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(currentRow,1,1,rowLength).getValues();
      var getSheetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
      var numberOfColumnsSheet = getSheetRange.getNumColumns();
      var numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow = numberOfColumnsSheet;
      var lastColumnInRange = String.fromCharCode(64 + (numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow));
      var range_string = 'C' + currentRow + ":" + lastColumnInRange + currentRow;
      var optionsArray = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(range_string).getValues();
      var choicesForQuestion =[];
      for (var j=0;j<optionsArray[0].length;j++)
      {
        choicesForQuestion.push(optionsArray[0][j]);
      }
      form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle(data[i][1]).setHelpText("").setChoiceValues(choicesForQuestion).setRequired(true); 

    }

    else
    {
      continue;
    }

  } 

  form.addParagraphTextItem()
  .setTitle('Please specify and attach relevant documents');          // add the text question at the last

  form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Identity - Asset Management').setHelpText("")();

}
```

[googleSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsDvr.png)

Comment: I have also attached my google spreadsheet at the bottom "googleSheet"

Comment: It would help if you formatted your code to make it more readable in the StackOverflow reader. Otherwise, this is a reasonable question to ask for being your first question!

Comment: Thanks @NoseKnowsAll !! Is there anything wrong with my code formatting. I mean in terms of reading it?

Comment: Yes there is some poor formatting. For instance, your brackets `{}` should all line up vertically so that it's visually easy to tell what's in the same code blocks. This also means everything inside the code blocks should be tabbed (well, 4 spaces). Those two fixes would make this question much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the same exact format for the next section you can get away with a simple counter. I have written a successful script variant, but it depends on what you really want.

Some of the changes I would do

```
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
  form.deleteItem(items[i])
}
```

instead of the current `form.deleteItem(0);`. Otherwise I see that you grab all the data, however you do not utilize it. Calling the spreadsheet app each time you want the options causes it to run a lot slower. More on that `for` loop: move the `Logger.log(data);` outside of the loop. There is no reason for you to keep logging the full data range each time you go to the next row of the data. Or change it to `Logger.log(data[i]);` which would make more sense.

You already do a

```
if (questionType=='') {
  continue;
}
```

to skip over the empty lines, so not really sure what that last `else` is meant for. The loop will fall through to the next option on its own anyway.

Now the way your set up would work is that your questions in the spreadsheet **must** be in order. That is you cannot have

- Section 1
- Section 2
- Section 1

as that will create 3 sections instead of 2. However let's move along with the assumption that the spreadsheet would only be set up in a way where you will only have a sequence like

- Section 1
- Section 1
- Section 2

In that case you should utilize your `data` and `questionType` by adding a counter `var sectionCount = 0` somewhere before the loop. Then inside of your `for` loop you do a simple

```
else if (questionType != sectionCount) {
  form.addSectionHeaderItem().setTitle('Section ' + questionType)
  sectionCount++
}
```

this will create the section (provided that the numbers are always increasing by 1 in Column A). Then in the same `for` loop you do not need any more `if` statements and can just use

```
items = data[i].slice(2, data[i].length + 1)
items = items.filter(chkEmpty)

form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle(data[i][1]).setChoiceValues(items)
```

where

```
function chkEmpty(val){
  return val != ''
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can program the google form responses in a way that I get I have my questions in the top row and the answers can automatically convert in to the numbers. As each choice value in the form is basically is on a scale from 1-5?

Comment: If you want the questions to have the options as they are, you could also store the relative column indexes in the script properties. So since we have an array of our choices we would do a `for` loop where inside of it we would do `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(items[i], i + 1)`. Then you would have a seperate function which would work with the response spreadsheet and simply get the responses, and use `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(answerString)` and set the answer to whatever digit you gave it

Comment: I have posted my updates solution below and i created a for loop just below the for loop `for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) { var answerstring = 0; PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(items[i]‌, i + 1)
}`. My response sheet is a different project file. How can i write a function to access a different sheet from a different project?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() 
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');

    var range = ss.getDataRange(); 
    var data = range.getValues();
    var numberRows = range.getNumRows();
    var numberColumns = range.getNumColumns();
    var firstRow = 1;
    var form = FormApp.openById('1xlXDZB5jhbUWpWHxxJwY-ut5oYkh4OfIQSTGsnwGTW4');
    var sectionCount = 0

    // deletes the previous changes 
    var items = form.getItems();
    var ilength = items.length;
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
    { 
    form.deleteItem(items[i])
    }


    for(var i=0;i<numberRows;i++)
    {
    var questionType = data[i][0]; 
    if (questionType=='')
    {
       continue;
    }


    else if (questionType != sectionCount ) 
    {
    if (sectionCount != 0 ) 
    { 
          //   form.addParagraphTextItem()
          // .setTitle('Please specify and attach relevant documents');                  // add the text question at the last

          // write the description here using SectionCount 

    }
        sectionCount++                                                        // add new section to the form

        form.addSectionHeaderItem().setTitle('Section ' + questionType).setHelpText("");    // add section header and title 

    } 
    items = data[i].slice(2, data[i].length + 1)
    items = items.filter(chkEmpty)
    form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle(data[i]  
   [1]).setChoiceValues(items).setRequired(true);

    if ( i == (numberRows-1)){
      //  form.addParagraphTextItem()
      //  .setTitle('Please specify and attach relevant documents');  
       }
     } 

     function chkEmpty(val)
     {
     return val != ''
     }

     Logger.log(data);
```

}