# How to make a google form using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to make a google form in apps script that will be like an inventory check out/in form. I want all the options to be under the check out section and every time a response gets submitted for checking out an item, the next time the form opens that item will appear under the check in section. I also want the item to go from check in to check out as well but I'm not even sure that functionality is available, just thought I'd put it out there. I started creating the form but I'm not sure where to go from here, the documentation for apps script isn't the most detailed.

```
//variable for new form
var newForm = FormApp.create('CS IT Checkout Form test');
//making name field
var name = newForm.addTextItem();
//variable for email
var email = newForm.addTextItem();
//variable for checkout checkboxes 
var checkBoxItem = newForm.adCheckBoxItem();
//variable for checkin checkboxes
var checkBoxItem2 = newForm.addCheckboxItem();
function myFunction() {
  //making description
  newForm.setDescription('Checkout and check-in form for CS tech');
  //making name field
  //at some point make the name field required or just do it in actual 
form
  name.setTitle('Name');
  //making email field
  email.setTitle('Email')
  //making checkout equipment fields
  checkoutItem.setTitle('Check Out');
  //default options until responses  are made then it begins to change
checkBoxItem.setChoiceValues(['Laptop', 'Tablet', 'Monitor', 'Camera']);
  //once form submissions start values will be put in the check in section 
  checkBoxItem2.setTitle('Check In');
  checkBoxItem2.setChoiceValues();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a google form from a google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113709/creating-a-google-form-from-a-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

Writing this as an answer rather than a comment because formatting.

First you have to figure out a flow that would work for what you want. Does this sound about right?

I think you need a form, and an inventory spreadsheet connected to that form.

The form asks the user whether it is a check/check out choice, and then the user select the appropriate item from the correct dropdown (check in or check out). I think you can tie this logic to a first page yes/no, but I haven't tried it. So worst case scenario three questions and they leave one dropdown blank. tie the form to the spreadsheet.

You need an onsubmit function in the spreadsheet that does the following:

- Determine whether the form was checking in or checking out
- Move the item to the appropriate sheet (two otherwise identical sheets for
  items that are checked in, and checked out).
- Update the values for the form with the right items in the dropdown

Now it is ready for the next usage. Is this what you envision?

Comment: Not really, when the form launches for first time all the items will be under a check out area since they are all available. One someone chooses whatever item they want to checkout, the next time the form opens that item shows up in the check in area. I essentially want a one page form that will simply move the items from one spot to another but in reality it's not that simple it seems like.

Comment: No, you'll need to store the information in a sheet and do some of the work from there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't need to store the information in a sheet, I figured out how to do it by making a function that gets the latest response and passes it to another function that creates a new choice for the new section